# What's the best way to "destroy" a purescript-halogen component when you're done using it?

Tags: lifecycle, purescript, halogen

I'm using Halogen to control a menu system for my application, and I'm wondering how I can "destroy" a Halogen component.  Right now, I have a function that creates a submenu component on a div with a particular ID.  Throughout the lifecycle of the app, the submenu could be visited multiple times, so currently multiple instances of the component are created whenever the `visitSubMenu` function is called.

```hs
import Halogen.Aff as HA
import Halogen.VDom.Driver (runUI)

visitSubMenu = do
  elem <- HA.selectElement "#submenu"
  case elem of
    (Just element) -> do
      liftEff $ HA.runHalogenAff do
        io <- runUI subMenuComponent unit element
        -- other code using component io...
```

Ideally, I'd like the submenu component to be removed when the user is done with their work in the submenu (i.e. the HTML injected into #submenu is removed, other cleanup happens).  Is that sort of thing possible?  I realize I could setup the component only one time at the start of the app, and keep it alive throughout the life of the app, but it seems better to me if I only set it up when it's needed.

---

I doubt this is the right way to do it, but my initial thought is I could create a lifecycleComponent, and when I want to destroy it, I can send a `Finalize` query and then manually remove the parent element from the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the only solution I found was to send a "Cleanup" query to the component, and then remove the root DOM element of the halogen component.

**FFI**

```
exports.removeElementById = function(id) {
  return function() {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e) e.remove();  
  }
}
```

**Halogen Component Module**

```
foreign import removeElementById :: String -> Eff (dom :: DOM | e) Unit

removeSelf :: forall e. Aff (dom :: DOM | e) Unit
removeSelf = liftEff $ removeElementById componentId

componentId :: String
componentId = "unique-id-for-component"

render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
render state = HH.div [HP.id_ componentId] []
```

So then I can call `removeSelf` when I'm finished using the component.